# Synaptics Touchpad Tap Lag (FastTaps Option Gone)

Tags: drivers, touchpad, tap

I own an Asus Zenbook Prime UX31A with a clickpad. Under the Synaptics driver, I'm trying to use tap-to-click. With the default settings, there is a very noticeable lag between when I tap and the tap is registered. Usually, I just set FastTaps to true in:

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

However, in the latest version of xf86-input-synaptics, FastTaps is no longer an option. I can set "SingleTapTimeout" to 0, which does make tapping instant, but then double tapping is impossible. Is there some way to make tapping instant while allowing for double tapping (and other related functions like tap-and-drag) in the latest Synaptics driver?

Answer (score 1):

In fact you were right about the parameter, but not the value. SingleTapTimeout is waiting for an integer (in ms). `"30"` works great for me.